# Select element does not display received value in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html-select

For some reason I fail to understand, my select element (with `ng-repeat`) does not display the value that was retrieved from the DB.

The source markup is:

```
<select class="form-control" 
        id="Test_Method_Select_{{$index}}" 
        ng-model="One_Source.Test_Method_Code" 
        style="width:150px">
    <option ng-repeat="One_Method in One_Source.Formatted_Test_Methods_List" value="{{One_Method.Value}}">
            {{One_Method.Value}} - {{One_Method.Name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

and the generated (by AngularJS) markup is:

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched" 
        id="Test_Method_Select_1" 
        ng-model="One_Source.Test_Method_Code" 
        style="width:150px">
    <option value="? number:26 ?"></option>
    <!-- ngRepeat: One_Method in One_Source.Formatted_Test_Methods_List -->
    <option ng-repeat="One_Method in One_Source.Formatted_Test_Methods_List" value="103" class="ng-binding ng-scope">103 - LC-MS-MS</option>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: One_Method in One_Source.Formatted_Test_Methods_List -->
    <option ng-repeat="One_Method in One_Source.Formatted_Test_Methods_List" value="26" class="ng-binding ng-scope">26 - Pesticides - GCMS</option>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: One_Method in One_Source.Formatted_Test_Methods_List -->
    <option ng-repeat="One_Method in One_Source.Formatted_Test_Methods_List" value="29" class="ng-binding ng-scope">29 - Aldicarb - LLE,GCMS</option>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: One_Method in One_Source.Formatted_Test_Methods_List -->
</select>
```

The element does not display **26 - Pesticides - GCMS** even though is the value shown to be the received one.

### Edit

Using Markus' suggestion, the source markup now looks as follows:

```
<select class="form-control" 
        id="Test_Method_Select_{{$index}}" 
        ng-model="One_Source.Test_Method_Code" 
        style="width:150px"
        ng-options="item.Value as (item.Value + '-' + item.Name) for item in One_Source.Formatted_Test_Methods_List">
</select>
```

Still, the selected value is not shown (note: I added `Value from model: {{One_Source.Test_Method_Code}}` just before the element and the correct value is shown, but not in the select element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at NgOptions instead. Here's a working example where I set the selected options in the controller by setting `$scope.One_Source.Test_Method_Code`

```js
angular.module("app",[]).controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
  $scope.One_Source = {};
  $scope.One_Source.Formatted_Test_Methods_List = [
  {
    value: 103,
    name: 'LC-MS-MS'
  },
  {
    value: 26,
    name: 'Pesticides - GCMS'
  },
  {
    value: 29,
    name: 'Aldicarb - LLE,GCMS'
  }
  ];
  $scope.One_Source.Test_Method_Code = 29;
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select class="form-control" 
        id="Test_Method_Select_{{$index}}" 
        ng-model="One_Source.Test_Method_Code" 
        style="width:150px"
        ng-options="item.value as (item.value + '-' + item.name) for item in One_Source.Formatted_Test_Methods_List">
</select> 
</div>
```

Comment: Markus, thanks for the quick response. I need the model to contain the value `29` only (i.e. without the `-Aldicarb - LLE,GCMS`. Is that going to be  the result? If not, how should I set the `ng-options` to achieve that?

Comment: Markus, I tested your suggestion and still, the value (29 in your example) is not being shown. I'll update the question with the new code for the source markup (2 mins...).

Comment: @FDavidov check that the value in One_Source.Test_Method_Code is a number

Comment: Marcus, in one word, **"BINGO"**. The issue was that the value field was a string. As soon as I wrapped it into a `Number()` function it all works as needed. Thank you Sir!!!!

Comment: @FDavidov NP, "BINGO" hehe epic